# adding multiple images to images as planes as image sequence not working

Tags: image

When I add multiple images as images as planes to my project the images don't stack as an image sequence but add multiple planes for each image.

When I add them manually on the image texture node, none is getting added and still only has one image.

I've tried setting the images to the same dimensions and set them to PNG but nothing is working.

my project renders in Evee and view transform is set to standard if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is intended or "works as designed". If you select multiple images Blender assumes that you want one "plane" per image.

If you want to use an image sequence, just select the first image, then go into shader editor, change single image to image sequence and frames to your number of frames.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, I've done something similar to this and done it again with your instructions, when i set the number of frames it goes back to one when i added the rest of the frames (including the first frame).

Comment: are the names of your files ending with  ...001.png ...002.png and so on?

Comment: oh! yes it worked when i've added the numbering at the end! truly thanks!

Comment: You are welcome